# My name can be written in two ways: arxiv struggles to list all my papers

Tags: arxiv, personal-name

My problem is the following:

I have a last name that is composed of two names. In some of my papers, the two names are hyphenated (in others, they aren't).

So basically my full name is either written as:

*Firstname Lastname1-Lastname2* or as *Firstname Lastname1 Lastname2*.

Because of that, it makes it harder for arxiv to find a complete list of my papers. In practice, if I click on my name in the paper preview on arxiv, it will list all papers associated with the either the first or second way of writing my name, but not both.

In order to solve the issue, I linked my arxiv account to my orcid, which is listing all my papers irrespectively of this issue. But this doesn't fix the issue on arxiv.

In summary: is there a way (without modifying my name in my previous papers) to fix this issue? I have an arxiv author id but there is the same kind of issue that it is not listing all my papers there.

Comment: What's the issue with the author ID? Can't you select all papers you have authored by logging in?

Comment: On a tangent: Are you aware of OrcID? Seems to be a particularly useful thing in your case.

Comment: @GoodDeeds the papers are related to my author Id. But when you click on someone name in arxiv it will do a research with its name rather than showing all the papers related to the author Id. Because of that, only either of the two way to write my name will be displayed when I click on my name for a given paper entry.

Comment: @OlegLobachev yes I am and my arxiv account is linked to my orcid.

Comment: I think your best chance is to spell your last name consistently (possibly updating old papers - it would be sufficient to do so in the arxiv author field, you need not update the paper itself). E.g. most spanish people I know either use a hyphen or just the first last name - the issue with the two last names w/out hyphen is that many people (and software) are unaware that this exists.

Comment: @StarBucK That's the default behaviour of arXiv, I don't think there is any solution to that (unless you resubmit your papers updating your name).

Comment: Is Arxiv that important in your field?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- yes, it is.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9382/is-a-researcher-with-the-same-name-in-a-different-field-likely-to-cause-confusio

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This seems rather orthogonal to the question.

Comment: @user151413 Both questions are based on the incorrect premise that ArXiv is an identity management system, so they should be linked to each other.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Just like orthogonal vectors are closely connected!

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the key to issues like this is *dogged consistency*. Once you decide how you want your name to appear on papers, that's the format you need to use in *every* paper and in *all* of your correspondence (at least in your signature block). Literally *everyone* should know you by the version of your name you selected. This is difficult for many people (including those with hyphenated last names) but is the only solution I've found.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a technical problem with the ArXiv treatment of author accounts.  It is unlikely to be easy to solve the problem externally, but presumably it could be solved internally with a reasonably simple change to the underlying code for the author accounts and search facilities on the site.

ArXiv is run by a group of researchers at Cornell University.  It has an [IT Advisory Group](https://arxiv.org/about/people/technical_ad_group) that meets several times per year to discuss an advise on IT problems relating to the site.  There is also a [Leadership Team](https://arxiv.org/about/people/leadership_team) that makes decisions relating to the site.  I recommend you contact the IT Advisory Group for ArXiv and let them know the problem you are having.  Since this is a volunteer group, they might also be willing to have you attend one of their meetings to discuss your problem with the group.  Many people have multiple surnames or multiple spellings of their surnames (it happens commonly with female researchers who change surnames after marriage) so this seems like a problem that would potentially affect many people, for which there ought to be a reasonably simple internal programming solution.