# what to do when someone has same name as yours and in IEEE search they show both peoples paper?

Tags: authorship, ieee, personal-name

I recently published a paper on `IEEE transactions journal`. in my paper link, when I click on authors tab and then my name,  another pages is opened and shows many papers but they are not mine. it seems, someone else has same name as me. Is this case common? what should I do?

Comment: Related: [Is a researcher with the same name in a different field likely to cause confusion?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9382/is-a-researcher-with-the-same-name-in-a-different-field-likely-to-cause-confusio)

Comment: Also related: [What are some practices for getting a name change so that people can find me more easily?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/512/what-are-some-practices-for-getting-a-name-change-so-that-people-can-find-me-mor)

Comment: Here's from the horse's mouth: **IEEE authors may request an update to their display name by submitting a request to onlinesupport@ieee.org ** http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplorehelp/#/searchingIeeeXplore/AuthorSearch/understandingAuthorSearch If it's due to how your name is displayed on IEEE Xplore, this should help. If not, I'm guessing that you can also ask them to correct their data if there is an error in their author identification.

Comment: Anyway, IEEE Xplore is notoriously poor when it comes to author identification. As you publish more papers, you'll start to see some papers missing when you click on your name in one paper, and another set of papers missing in another list you arrive at from a different paper of yours. And both of them probably have tons of papers by others. It's disastrous if your name is a common Chinese one. (And by common, I mean you've got lots of namesakes when transliterated in the Latin alphabet, regardless of whether they're spelled differently in Chinese.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a very common problem.

1. You should publish with the most complete version of your name possible (e.g. use your middle name.)  Think very carefully before changing your name (e.g. if you get married.)
2. You should establish profiles with services that keep track of publications by author (including Google Scholar, Thompson's MyResearcherID, and ORCID)  and then "claim" your publications using these ID's.

Comment: I made an account based on your second suggestion. But it was my complete name. There are a lot of people with my name in this country. Now my scholar account doesn't appear in the search results when I Google it. Is it because they have more citation than me? , We both have same name .@brian-borchers